# Multiline Regex Matching Issue

Tags: java, regex

I have the following string that I am trying to match via regex:

```
;IF TEST_DATE <= 200112 THEN E>=90 AND S>=90
 OR P = "25" ENDIF
IF TEST_DATE >= 200201 AND TEST_DATE < 200407 THEN E>=89
AND S>=90 OR P = "25" ENDIF
```

I am using the following regex in an attempt to match from the semicolon (intended to be a comment) until the first ENDIF:

```
;\s*IF (\d|\D)+ ENDIF
```

Unfortunately, this pattern matches all the way until the second ENDIF. I've tried various solutions using the Java Pattern.DOTALL, as well as the (?s) flag, with no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `greedy` quantifier, due to which your pattern `(\d|\D)` matches everything till it finds the last `ENDIF`.

You need to use `reluctant quantifier - +?` if you want your regex to stop matching at the first `ENDIF` : -

```
;\s*IF (\d|\D)+? ENDIF
```

Comment: My regex-fu is weak. Thanks for your help. (I'll accept as soon as it lets me)

Answer (score 1):

Use the non-greedy qualifier.

```
;\s*IF (\d|\D)*? ENDIF
```